# Generalization in ProGuard's "keep" arguments

Tags: java, android, scala, proguard, sbt-android-plugin

ProGuard defines it's "keep" syntax [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html#classspecification).

```
[@annotationtype] [[!]public|final|abstract|@ ...] [!]interface|class|enum classname
    [extends|implements [@annotationtype] classname]
[{
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static|volatile|transient ...] <fields> |
                                                                      (fieldtype fieldname);
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static|synchronized|native|abstract|strictfp ...] <methods> |
                                                                                           <init>(argumenttype,...) |
                                                                                           classname(argumenttype,...) |
                                                                                           (returntype methodname(argumenttype,...));
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static ... ] *;
    ...
}]
```

Is it possible to keep use generalized modifiers and types?
For example `-keep * * my.package.MySomething { *; }`
The 1st `*` would mean anything from this part: `[!]public|final|abstract|@ ...]`, and
the 2nd `*` would mean anything from this part: `[!]interface|class|enum`.

In bit more depth, I am trying to generate ProGuard arguments dynamically and I do NOT know whether `my.package.MySomething` is an `abstract class` or `public enum` or anything else.

Is there a way, an option in ProGuard that could help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration

```
-keep class my.package.MySomething { *; }
```

does what you want. You'd only add access modifiers if you'd want to further constrain the matches (e.g. public; or interface instead of class).